# Javascript onclick doesn't work with dynamically generated rails elements?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails block like this -

```
  <% if blah%>
    <% foo(100).each_with_index do |data| %>
      <img src="<%= data %>" onclick="yay(<%= data %>)">
   <% end %>
```

And `yay()` should log the value of data.

However, the dynamically generated elements from the rails method `foo()` don't work with `onclick`. A static image does. Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to surround the <%= data %> with single quotes like so:

```
<img src="<%= data %>" onclick="yay('<%= data %>')">
```

Otherwise, it will treat it like a JavaScript variable which will cause it to fail.

Check out the console of your browser and you should see a message complaining about this.